# Why can the type constraint `std::convertible_to` be used with only one template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, c++20, c++-concepts

I've scrolled and searched through [the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto) and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) for hours to no avail, would really appreciate if someone could explain this occurance for me:

I am looking at the standard concept [`std::convertibe_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to). Here's a simple example that I do understand

```cpp
class A {};
class B : public A {};

std::convertible_to<A, B>; // false
std::convertible_to<B, A>; // true
```

Works as expected.

Now there is also another possible way to use it, that I don't quite understand

```
void foo(std::convertible_to<A> auto x) { /* ... */ }
```

, and this function can easily accept any type convertible to A. This is weird though, because the first template parameter ("From") is essencially dropped, and deduced on function call. This following function would also work, and I'm fairly certain it's actually equivalent to the previous one

```
template<typename T, std::convertible_to<T> S>
void foo(S x) { /* ... */ }
```

again the type of `x` is deduced when we call `foo`.

This works, despite the template requiring two parameters. I tried also with `std::derived_from` and it seems to work. This form of specifying a concept with only one template parameter even appears in the standard itself, so there must be some piece of syntax that explains it.

Notice that [the only version](https://eel.is/c++draft/concept.convertible) of `std::convertible_to` that exists is in fact one that takes two template parameters.

Could anyone clarify why this works?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
void foo( constraint<P0, P1, P2> auto x );
```

this translates roughly to

```
template<contraint<P0, P1, P2> X>
void foo( X x );
```

which translates roughly to

```
template<class X> requires constraint<X, P0, P1, P2>
void foo( X x );
```

notice how the type `X` is *prepended* to the template arguments of the constraint.

So in your case,

```
template<typename T, std::convertible_to<T> S>
void foo(S x) { /* ... */ }
```

is roughly

```
template<typename T, class S>
requires std::convertible_to<S, T>
void foo(S x) { /* ... */ }
```

(I say roughly, because I believe they are not exactly equivalent in subtle ways.  For example, the second one introduces the name `X`, while the first does not.  And there are probably other differences of similar scale; what I mean is that understanding the translation will give you an understanding of what is translated.  This is unlike `for(:)` loop-`for(;;)` loop correspondence; the standard specifies `for(:)` loops in terms of `for(;;)` loops, which isn't what I'm claiming above.)

Comment: Final sentence: `s/not like/not unlike/`?

Comment: @Quuxplusone No.  `for(:)` loops are defined as a literal translation of the user-written C++ code into a specific bit of `for(;;)` code (with some variables with secret names) loop.  It is a quirky bit of the standard.  The equivalence above isn't nearly as direct, as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, I see the distinction you're making now, although I think it's *way* too subtle for this context. So personally I'd characterize it as "...not like, but _also_ not unlike,..." ;)

Comment: @Quuxplusone _almost, but not quite, entirely unlike_...

Answer (score 7):

There are several locations where a `concept` name can be used where the first argument to the template concept is not supplied in the template argument list. Constraining an `auto` deduced variable is one of them.

The first argument in these cases is provided by some expression, typically using template argument deduction rules. In the case of a constrained function parameter, the first argument is determined by the template function itself. That is, if you call `foo(10)`, template argument deduction will deduce the `auto` template parameter as an `int`. Therefore, the full concept will be `convertible_to<int, A>`.